Convert Svelte 4 stores to Svelte 5 $state with Client-side Component API
Given this Svelte 4 setup REPL
<script>
    import Comp from './Comp.svelte'
    import {writable, derived, get} from 'svelte/store'

    function newCustomStore() {
        const store = writable({1: 'foo'})

        return {
            subscribe: store.subscribe,
            set: store.set,

            getEntry(id) {
                return get(store)[id]
            }
        }
    }

    function newDeviceStore(deviceMap, id) {
        return derived(deviceMap, $deviceMap => {
            return deviceMap.getEntry(id)
        })
    }

    const store = newCustomStore()
    const entryStore = newDeviceStore(store, 1)

    function handleOpenComp() {
        const comp = new Comp({
            target: document.body,
            props:{
                entry: entryStore
            }
        })
    }
</script>

<!-- not reactive  -->
{store.getEntry(1)} <br>

<!-- reactive -->
{$entryStore} <br>

<button on:click={handleOpenComp}>
    open comp
</button>

<button on:click={() => $store[1]= $store[1] + 'o'}>
    click
</button> <br>

Component.svelte
<script>
  export let entry
</script>

<!-- reactive -->
{$entry}

It works to pass a derived store to the component that is reactive to changes of the store it's derived from.
When I transform this to Svelte 5 REPL
<script>
    import { mount } from 'svelte';
    import Comp from './Comp.svelte'
    import {writable} from 'svelte/store'

    let target

    class Store {
        value = $state({1: 'foo'})

        getEntry(id) {
            return this.value[id]
        }
    }

    let store = new Store()

    let props = $derived({ entry: store.getEntry(1)})
    
    function handleOpenComp() {
        const comp = mount(Comp, {
            target: document.body,
            props: props
        })
    }
</script>

<!-- reactive -->
{store.getEntry(1)} <br>

<!-- reactive -->
{props.entry} <br>

<button onclick={handleOpenComp}>
    open comp
</button>

<button onclick={() => store.value[1] = store.value[1] + 'o'}>
    click
</button>

<br>

Comp.svelte
<script>
    let {entry} = $props()  
</script>

<!-- not reactive -->
{entry}

the $derived props won't react to changes. The docs say

"...use $state instead to create a reactive property object and manipulate it."

 const props = $state({ foo: 'bar' });
 const app = mount(App, { target: document.getElementById("app"), props });
 props.foo = 'baz';

I seem to be wrong to assume, that when passing $state should work, passing $derived should do so as well...? How can I achieve the same behaviour in Svelte 5?

$derived doesn't reactifies the value, the variable itself is reactive.
For the value, you create an object and populate it with a primitive value ("foo"), so there is nothing reactive.
The variable is reactive only within its scope. Thus, when you pass props, the value that is non-reactive from the beginning goes beyond the props scope.
You can use closure to keep reactivity:
            props: {
                get entry() { return props.entry }
            }

Reading entry in the child component will cause reading props, and thus reactivity will be passed.

Thanks for the answer! It's working with your getter approach and It's actually working when changing "foo" to an object - then even without props as $derived or $state, but directly with props: { entry: store.getEntry(1) } When passing a $derived holding a string as a prop to a component there's no problem with reactivity so I find it hard to grasp why it's different here

@Corrl: Because the values are copied, not referenced. This works as well: let props = { get entry() { return store.getEntry(1); } };. The problem with the $derived is that a new object is created every time with a fixed value that loses the reference to the original state. You then pass the current copy, so later changes to the local variable do not affect the previously constructed component.
